# Need help building an SQLAlchemy query + subquery

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, subquery

This is the SQL I need SQLAlchemy to generate via its ORM.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    notes
WHERE
    notes.student_id == {student_id} 
  OR
    notes.student_id IN (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            peers
        WHERE
            peers.student_id == {student_id}
          AND
            peers.date_peer_saved >= notes.date_note_saved
    )
```

The SQL is untested. I just wrote it to demo what I need SQLAlchemy to do.

Basically, the logged in student should see a list of saved `notes`. The only `notes` the student should see, however, are those posted by themself or those posted by one of their peers - But only those peers they 'friended' after the note had been saved.

This way, a student won't see notes posted by another student before they became peers.

I'm having trouble getting this to run in SQLAlchemy's ORM, however. Any help?

Answer (score 8):

Basically, you can use the `.subquery()` method to get a sub query that you can place into another conditional like that.

Something like

```
subq = sess.query(Peers.id).filter(and_(Peers.student==student, XXX)).subquery()
```

Then

```
notes = sess.query(Notes).filter(or_(Notes.student==student, Notes.studing.in_(subq))).all()
```

(also untested and may not work with this actual query, but just to give you the idea).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because there are problems with the query.

It looks like you want to see all notes for a student id where `date_peer_saved` is >= `date_note_saved`.

The problem is that the tables `notes` and `peers` are probably Many to One relationship with `student`.  What this means is that you are trying to filter records of `peers` where there may be many notes and many peers to compare.

You need to join all three tables in such a way that each record of `peers` relates to a single record of `notes`.  If this doesn't apply to you then you need to rethink what you really are asking for.

Perhaps you want to filter the MAX of date_peer_saved >= MAX of date_note_saved?